# My program doesn't output the first value I entered to search in my array. Why?

Tags: c

For example, if I write 1,2,3,4,5 for my array and I write again 1,2,3,4,5 to search in the array it doesn't output 1... I am confused. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int i, b, c, n, a;
  int ara[200];
  int number[200];

  printf("Please enter how many numbers you wanna input: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n > 200) {
    // i limited the numbers users can input.
    printf("You can't write higher than 200. It's out of range. ");
  } else {
    printf("Please write %d numbers: \n", n);
  }

  // i asked for numbers from user.
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf(" %d", &number[i]);
  }

  // I asked for a number to search from the inputted array.
  printf("Please enter numbers to search: \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  n = n - 1;
  for (int a = 0; a < n; ++a) {
    scanf("%d", &ara[a]);
  }

  n = n + 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  // my program looks every line to find the number.

    for (a = 0; a < n; ++a) {
      // if program can find a number equals to the ones in array, it will print
      // the line.
      if (number[i] == ara[a]) {
        // i wrote i+1 because normally number 1 is considered as number 0 in
        // arrays.
        printf("%d is at position %d in the array.\n", ara[a], i + 1);
        // break; //to stop the loop.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed a few lines on your code now it works as expected check it yourself please:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int i, b, c, n, a;
  int ara[200];
  int number[200];

  printf("Please enter how many numbers you wanna input: \n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n > 200) {
    // i limited the numbers users can input.
    printf("You can't write higher than 200. It's out of range. ");
  } else {
    printf("Please write %d numbers: \n", n);
  }

  // i asked for numbers from user.
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    scanf(" %d", &number[i]);
  }

  // I asked for a number to search from the inputted array.
  printf("Please enter numbers to search: \n");
//   scanf("%d", &a); // Your major problem was beginning from here.

  for (int a = 0; a < n; ++a) {
    scanf("%d", &ara[a]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  // my program looks every line to find the number.

    for (a = 0; a < n; ++a) {
      // if program can find a number equals to the ones in array, it will print
      // the line.
      if (number[i] == ara[a]) {
        // i wrote i+1 because normally number 1 is considered as number 0 in
        // arrays.
        printf("%d is at position %d in the array.\n", ara[a], i + 1);
        // break; //to stop the loop.
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

Now it outputs something like following:

```
[kozmotronik@kozmotronik-ge600nc0nd Belgeler]$ ./karalama
Please enter how many numbers you wanna input: 
4
Please write 4 numbers: 
3
5
3
7
Please enter numbers to search: 
3
4
5
7
3 is at position 1 in the array.
5 is at position 2 in the array.
3 is at position 3 in the array.
7 is at position 4 in the array.
```

**Update to improve readability and effieciency**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
  int i, b, c, n, a;
  int ara[200];
  int number[200];

  printf("Please enter how many numbers you wanna input: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  if (n > 200) {
    // i limited the numbers users can input.
    printf("You can't write higher than 200. It's out of range. ");
  } else {
    printf("Please write %d numbers:\n", n);
  }

  // i asked for numbers from user.
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d. number: ",i+1);
    scanf(" %d", &number[i]);
  }

  // First ask how many numbers the user wants to search.
  printf("\nHow many numbers will be searched?: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  for (int s = 0; s < a; ++s) {
    printf("%d. number to search: ",s+1);
    scanf("%d", &ara[s]);
  }

  /* A better approach is to iterate in the outer loop for each number to be searched
   * instead of iterateing for the numbers in the list.
   */
  bool found;
  for (i = 0; i < a; ++i) {  // In the outer loop iterate for the numbers to be searched.
    found = false; // Set found to false for each new number to be searched 
    for (b = 0; b < n; ++b) { // In the inner loop iterate for the list
      // if program can find a number equals to the ones in array, it will print
      // the line.
      if (number[b] == ara[i]) {
        // i wrote i+1 because normally number 1 is considered as number 0 in
        // arrays.
        printf("%d is at position %d in the array.\n", ara[i], b + 1);
        found = true; // set found to true if you find it
      }
    }
    
    if(!found){
        printf("The number <%d> does not exist in the list\n",ara[i]);
    }
  }
  
}
```

Updated code outputs like following:

```
Please enter how many numbers you wanna input: 8
Please write 8 numbers:
1. number: 100
2. number: 2345
3. number: 457
4. number: 234
5. number: 2
6. number: 657
7. number: 4
8. number: 900

How many numbers will be searched?: 4
1. number to search: 4
2. number to search: 23
3. number to search: 657
4. number to search: 15
4 is at position 7 in the array.
The number <23> does not exist in the list
657 is at position 6 in the array.
The number <15> does not exist in the list
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is hard for me to see my mistakes as a beginner. Such a helpful answer!

Comment: There you have an update in your code. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is undefined to to reading uninitialzed memory. I can prove that no matter what the input is to this program, it will eventually read `ara[n-1]` which was never initialized due to the lines `n = n - 1;` and `n = n + 1;`. If the compiler manages to do this induction, it can delete the entire nested `for` loop as modern compilers assume undefined behavior implies unreachable code.

Also this scanf line is wrong: `scanf("%d", &a);` Reading into `a` doesn't work. Neither does reading into `n`. You need another integer to store how many numbers are in the search array. You can't use `n` for both.

Comment: Thank you so much I am a newbie so I got so lost I am trying to learn. As you said I rearranged "the number searching part" and put new integers to store my values and now it's working. It was really helpful!